# SQL Server JBDC Driver comparison

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jtds

Currently we use [jtds](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) for connecting to our SQL Server databases. I've always taken it for granted that we use it due to performance and reliability reasons, however, it's usage pre-dates my employment.

All of that being said, we are now playing with the idea of moving to SQL Server 2008, which jtds has limited support for. Initial tests seem to indicate that jtds has better performance than the Microsoft supplied driver on 2005.

So my question is does anyone have any empirical evidence or any other good information otherwise indicating which jdbc driver is best suited for use with SQL Server 2005 and\or 2008?

Is jtds better? The driver supplied by Microsoft? Something else?

I've thought about profiling, but have doubts about whether this will really prove anything.

Answer (score 3):

We had experience using the MSFT driver vs JTDS and we chose WITH NO DOUBTS the JTDS driver.
Got less UNK problems, better performance and reliability. 
Not have any chart to demostrate, but our product is a POS for gas stations with more than 3k installations.

We are sql 2005, didn't tried in 2008.

Comment: Something to be mindful of is that jTDS doesn't actually support XA (distributed) transactions. The official Microsoft driver does. For more information see http://jtds.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jtds/branches/jTDS%201.2%20%28stable%29/README.XA?revision=1118&view=markup

Answer (score 2):

Is using [the JDBC driver supplied by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937724.aspx) an option?

Seems like it's kept up-to-date: supports JDBC 4.0, and MSSQL 2000/2005/2008.

Comment: That is really what I am comparing to jtds to, sorry - I should have made that clearer.