# is JTDS driver outdated?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jtds

I'm now trying to decide which driver to use to create a DataSource from my JavaEE application to MS SqlServer.

A couple of years ago I had good experience with [JTDS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/), and [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1214188/513342) suggest that JTDS was a preference back then.

But now I can see that its latest version 1.2.5 is [two years old](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/jtds/1.2.5/) (2009-12-30).

Is it a good enough reason to choose MS proprietary driver, or is JTDS so good that it doesn't require any development anymore? :)

Comment: (Just as a general comment, it's JTDS, not JDTS. I've edited your question throughout.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft [JDBC driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724) is **JDBC 4.0** compliant while jTDS is **JDBC 3.0**.

[Here](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/10/whats-new-in-jdbc-40.html#new-features-in-jdbc-40) are some new features and improvements introduced in version 4.0 of JDBC.

Comment: I'm not sure that I need JDBC 4.0 features because I'm doing the same old stuff that I was doing when 4.0 was not available, but [looking further](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8413767/513342) I found that proprietary driver might be even faster. Will accept your answer if no one proves the contrary.

Comment: I have never used MS driver either :). jTDS had never let me down and I heard it outperforms MS driver.

Comment: JTDS has better features (eg Windows Auth from Windows etc). Older MS JDBC didn't support SSL either

Comment: JTDS is more convenient to use because it is available from Maven repo. So I'm hoping someone will persuade me that being old doesn't mean being outdated.

Comment: Eeek, I didn't know this. I'll have to review [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) for some `Blob.free()` and `Clob.free()` usage, and similar things!

Comment: *"JTDS is more convenient to use because it is available from Maven repo."* - As of November 2016, Microsoft's JDBC Driver for SQL Server is [open source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jdbcteam/2016/11/17/open-source-jdbc-maven/) and [available from Maven](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.microsoft.sqlserver%22%20AND%20a%3A%22mssql-jdbc%22).

Comment: Microsoft's JDBC Driver for SQL Server is in maven and it's actively being maintained.  jTDS seems dead since Jun 08, 2013